# Multiple updatepanel update same time

Tags: asp.net

I have three Update panel in a page. When I want to submit First Button then only show the value first updatepanel's value another updatepanel's value should not be accepted.

And in the second updatepanel same as firt, when I clicked second button only take second updatepanel's  value.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ThreeUpdatepanel.aspx.cs" Inherits="ThreeUpdatepanel" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div><asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    </div>
  <br />
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" >
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
  <br />
  <br />

   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
  <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server">
       </asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Button ID="UPD1" runat="server" Text="UPD1" onclick="UPD1_Click" /> 

  </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
   <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
  <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox id="TextBox2" runat="server">
       </asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Button ID="UPD2" runat="server" Text="UPD2" onclick="UPD2_Click" />
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UPD1" EventName ="Click" />
  <%--<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="UPD2" />--%>
  </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class ThreeUpdatepanel : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {

            }
        }
        protected void UPD1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             // My question is that when i click this button then also collected the value of another UpdatePanel(UpdatePanel2) TextBox(TextBox2.Text)
             //Expected Result is TextBox2 value should be blank when i submit this button.
            //UpdatePanel1.Update();

            string x = TextBox2.Text;
            Label1.Text = "You select: " + TextBox1.Text + ' ' + TextBox2.Text;
        }
        protected void UPD2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // My question is that when i click this button then also collected the value of another UpdatePanel(UpdatePanel1) TextBox(TextBox1.Text)
            //Expected Result is TextBox1 value should be blank when i submit this button.
            //UpdatePanel2.Update();

            string xx = TextBox1.Text; 
            Label1.Text = "You select: " + TextBox2.Text + ' ' +TextBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

Both time update message should be show third updatepanel's label.

Please give me some idea or give some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in multiple ways,

1. Put the first button inside the first update panel.
2. Put the second button inside the second update panel.
3. put two `AsyncPostBackTrigger` inside the third update panel.

the next way is,

1. Put `AsyncPostBackTrigger` for the first button in first update panel and third update panel
2. Put `AsyncPostBackTrigger` for second button in second and third update panels.
3. Place buttons anywhere you want.

In both ways you can update the all three labels and update panels will take care of what need to be updated.

Comment: taking both TextBox value when i clicked any button!! Not my expected result...my expected result is..it does not matter when i clicked first button inside updatepanel1 only takes value of TextBox1 though TextBox2 is also filled.